# Intermittent hang after systemd startup on Debian Buster

Tags: debian, systemd, initramfs, freeze, hang

I'm currently running Debian Buster with the 4.19.0-9-amd64 kernel. I find that intermittently after booting my system, selecting this kernel, entering my boot disk encryption key, and waiting for systemd to launch its services, my screen will clear, but will not proceed to launch my WM from that point. (as a note, 4.19.0-10-amd64 appears to cause this behavior 100% of the time)

Normally, I expect my primary monitor to turn off between systemd's services starting and my WM login screen appearing, but that does not happen in these cases–instead, my system will hang on an apparently empty terminal screen (which does not animate or respond to input) until it is hard rebooted. To my knowledge, this has always occurred, even on a fresh Debian install with little-to-no other software installed.

The only other thing I could find which seems odd is that every time I boot, before prompting me for my encrypted disk key, I see the following lines:

```
  volume group "debian-vg" not found
  Cannot process volume group debian-vg
  volume group "debian-vg" not found
  Cannot process volume group debian-vg
```

I suspect they are not related, but this is the only oddity I can pinpoint in my boot.log.

My graphics drivers are nvidia's proprietary drivers, with my machine running two SLI'd GTX 770 cards. My desktop environment is KDE Plasma.

The [output of `sudo dmesg` is too long to add to this post, and is posted to Debian's pastezone](https://paste.debian.net/hidden/3278ed3b/).

Comment: Those volume group errors are unrelated. I see them all the time.

Comment: You say "I'm currently running". Does this mean the same Buster did run on this machine before? If so, what has changed since then?

Comment: It wasn't meant to imply anything else. This machine used to run Windows 7, but the installation of Debian is on its own hard drive and is prioritized in BIOS, so it is not dual-booted or otherwise different than it would be were it installed originally on its own.

Comment: can you try to boot into muli-user.target? https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/01/how-to-boot-to-console-text-mode-in.html this way you can exclude problems with the graphics-driver

Comment: @blaimi I was able to consistently launch in multi-user.target mode, and each time I tried in visual mode I encountered the same hang.

Comment: this seems to be a problem with your graphic-card and drivers and stuff. can you provide some information on that? what grapic-card are you using and what driver? and which dm are you using? gdm?

Comment: Check `systemd-analyze blame`

Comment: Post the output of `sudo dmesg`

Comment: I've added information on my drivers and graphics cards. `systemd-analyze blame` did not have any apparently interesting results. I've also added a link to the output of `sudo dmesg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the posting of this questing, I've upgraded my system to Debian 11 (Bullseye), and with that upgrade I'm no longer seeing this hang. I presume some DE package was at fault and was upgraded in the process. I still encounter the "debian-vg" lines at startup, but the don't seem to impact it in any way.

Answer (score 0):

This vg is your root file system for the kernel - in kernel settings at boot. It is not found, so it is not mounted, so kernel cannot use it as root file system.

```
... root=/dev/mapper/debian--vg-root ...
```

Kernel earlier should know that he needs to recognize this vg, before it can be taken as root file system.

Comment: I don't understand, how is that related to the intermittent hang I'm experiencing?

Comment: @Nightfirecat the hang is from missing root fs. I had hangs like that.

Comment: What would be the solution for this then? Does this vg need to be created, or do the kernel settings need to be changed to some other vg? How would I make those changes in a way which will persist permanently?

Comment: @Nightfirecat you need to mount this vg earlier before kernel will use it as root fs. It is already created, it is a working root fs, so you don't need to recreate it.